# General strategies for choosing priors and samplers to estimate parameters of nonlinear ODE system?

Tags: bayesian, sampling

I'm new to MCMC methods, and as I learn, it seems there is a lot of art in choosing the proper priors especially when there are many parameters (which is why we use MCMC in the first place).

Are there any strategies that go into which distributions are suitable for which scenarios or parameter types? Coming from physics systems, the naive way I use is truncated normals or uniform distributions, however, the results I'm getting are not great. Maybe there are more clever distributions that I can use for better results? Maybe different distributions for parameters that are powers?

As for samplers, I was wondering about that too. Metropolis-Hastings is a go-to, but it seems like NUTS gets the same results but in less computational time. Are there other options to consider in relation to ODE parameters? What methods can one use to improve the sampling process?

I know these very broad questions, but I couldn't find too many (beginner-level) practical examples when it comes to Bayesian parameter estimation for ODE systems, so I guess this post can be beneficial for many people who are stepping into this world.